# I cannot install sysstat on Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: apt

When I try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sysstat` I get the following:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 sysstat : Depends: libsensors4 (>= 1:3.0.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As far as I can tell, there are no held broken packages.  I've tried a bunch of other things, like:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: it installs on mine (from 'main')  - check your `sources.list file`; esp. if its not a Canonical Ubuntu (ie. a modified unofficial-version provided by cloud providers etc)

Comment: What other things have you tried, please list them?

Comment: @George ok, done.